# Connect to Elastic Enterprise Search using Node.js

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, elastic-cloud

I have following code to connect to Elastic Search Using Cloud ID

```
const { Client } = require('@elastic/elasticsearch')
//or using elastic.Client from ('elasticsearch')

var client = new Client({
    cloud: {
        id: 'cloudId'
    },
    auth: {
        username: "elastic",
        password: "eleastic_password",
    },

});
```

I can add and query data using above connection but I want the data to be queried from and added to Enterprise Search Cluster I have.. How can I make connection to Enterprise Search and not Kibana using nodejs? Apart from using http requests/axios, is there a way I can connect to Enterprise Search App cluster on Elastic Search using the Endpoint API Url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So since I didn't get any answers. I finally found the way to connect to elastic enterprise search and that is by host url.
Like this

```
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
// do not forget to add the username and password in the url
  host:"https://<username>:<password>[complete_host_url]" 
});
```

One can also connect to multiple hosts at a time by providing the host value as array of host urls.

Comment: Yes, it works... I had same problem, now it connects without any issues

Comment: Glad it helped :)